# Read version from Info.plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, info.plist

I want to read the bundle version info from Info.plist into my code, preferably as a string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You can read your Info.plist as a dictionary with

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]
```

And you can easily get the version at the `CFBundleVersion` key that way.

Finally, you can get the version with

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* version = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Comment: Perfect. That's a lot simpler than all the lines of CF* functions I was using... I was sure there must have been a quick way to get the NSDictionary.

Comment: For the version number, this doesn't matter, but for other keys you might want to use `objectForInfoDictionaryKey:` instead, since it returns the localized value if available: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]`

Comment: Note in Xcode4 if you look at the target's summary panel you'll see Version & Build fields. `CFBundleVersion` has been repurposed to be Build and Version is `CFBundleShortVersionString`.

Comment: This will fetch both version & build number, and format them together:    `NSString *version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];`
    `NSString *build = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];`
    `self.versionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", version, build];`

Comment: use CFBundleShortVersionString as key for objectForKey method.

Comment: I think also for version number `objectForInfoDictionaryKey:` is desirable, because what's called "Product version" (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) can contain text and be localized.

Answer (score 13):

for Swift users:

```
if let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") {
    print("version is : \(version)")
}
```

for Swift3 users:

```
if let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") {
    print("version is : \(version)")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that some time has passed since the quest and the answer.

**Since iOS8 the accepted answer might not work.**

This is the new way to do it now:

```
NSString *version = (__bridge id)CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), kCFBundleVersionKey);
```

Comment: Do you have a link to why this is so?

Answer (score 4):

Now in iOS 8 both fields are necessary. Earlier it works without the `CFBundleShortVersionString`. But now it is a required plist field to submit any app in app store. And `kCFBundleVersionKey` is compared for uploading every new build, which must be in incremental order. Specially for TestFlight builds. I do it this way,

```
NSString * version = nil;
    version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    if (!version) {
        version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks .. **version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];** worked for me

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3:**

```
let appBuildNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
```