# iOS: Access app-info.plist variables in code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, info.plist

I am working on a Universal app & would like to access the values stored in app-info.plist file in my code.

Reason: I instantiate a UIViewController dynamically from a storyboard using:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExampleViewController"];
```

Now, having the storyboard name @"MainStoryboard_iPhone" above is ugly.

I want to do something like:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:appInfo.mainStoryboardBaseNamePhone bundle:nil];
self = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExampleViewController"];
```

where appInfo can perhaps be an NSDictionary of all values in app-info.plist

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Attributes from the info.plist for your project are directly accessible by the following...

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:key_name];
```

For example to get the version number you might do the following

```
NSString *appVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

There is a gotcha in that the version number now has two attributes in the info.plist - but you get the idea? If you view your info.plist as source code (right click the info.plist - select Open As) then you will get to see all the various key names you can use.

Comment: As mentioned by @Answerbot in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/a/4059118/1210822 : "CFBundleVersion has been repurposed to be Build and Version is CFBundleShortVersionString", so now for retrieving the version number from plist, we need to use: NSString *version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

Comment: for 11.3 it doesn't work, because NSBundle was renamed and the new Bundle has it not included yet. Do xou have a Update?

Comment: If I have an Enterprise iOS app that is distributed via the web, can I add key/value pairs in the PLIST file, and subsequently read those values from the app at the time of download?

Comment: how we can update value of CFBundleVersion from the AppDelegate.m?

Answer (score 36):

**Swift 4+** syntax for [Damo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9530129/3659227)

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "KEY_NAME")
```

Example

```
let appVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion")
```

Comment: For beginners like me, `Bundle` requires `import SystemConfiguration`

Answer (score 12):

Well you can acces the info.plist very easly :

Getting the name of the storyboard:

```
NSString *storyboard  = [[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
```

Not sure wether it will detect if it is in a iPad and it should use the `UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad` key instated.

Comment: XCode automatically populates the key 'UIMainStoryboardFile' with the iPhone / iPad Storyboard files, depending on the device :)

Answer (score 9):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"YOURPLISTNAME" ofType: @"plist"]; 
NSMutableDictionary *dictplist =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: You can also use NSDictionary: `NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the infoDictionary method on NSBundle:

```
NSDictionary *infoPlistDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *version = infoPlistDict[@"CFBundleVersion"];
```