# Getting data from the Info plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Whenever I want to get data from a plist file I use the following code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FILE_NAME" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

But now I'm trying to read in data from the Info plist, and filePath is nil. Is there a different way to get data from the Info plist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS: Access app-info.plist variables in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530075/ios-access-app-info-plist-variables-in-code)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From an earlier [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530075/ios-access-app-info-plist-variables-in-code/9530129#9530129) answer of mine. Attributes from the info.plist for your project are directly accessible by the following...

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:key_name];
```

Your filePath is nil simply because it can't find the file - check spellings & check if the file you are trying to read from is actually in the bundle etc.

Comment: I was able to get the plist using [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary. The info plist was not in the Copy Bundle Resources list for the target. Is the info plist stored somewhere else?

Comment: Swift version if anyone needs it `Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "key_name")`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is another way (unless it is the info.plist file then see Damo's comment), instead I would focus on figuring out why the filePath is nil, perhaps the plist file is no longer under target>build phases>copy bundle resources?

Comment: I was able to get the plist using [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary. The info plist was not in the Copy Bundle Resources list. I guess there is something special about the info plist?

Comment: Well spotted - I never would have thought that but upon checking my current project the info.plist is also unchecked for copy

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FILE_NAME" ofType:@"plist"]
```

with

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Info" ofType: @"plist"]
```