# Ios Swift Looping through Fonts provided by application in info.plist

Tags: ios, fonts, swift2, info.plist, font-family

*Using Xcode 7 and swift 2*

> I have assigned a string for each font in Info.plist -> Fonts provided by application -> Array
>
> How do i loop through all these fonts and assign in for loop

I tried : Output was nil

```
var familyList = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("Fonts provided by application") as [String]
```

I came across below code which gives me list of all family names, which i dont need.

I Need same to loop only with fonts i have added.

```
for family: AnyObject in UIFont.familyNames() {
    println("Font Family: \(family)")
    for font: AnyObject in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family as NSString) {
        println("Font Name: \(font)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `let fonts = NSBundle.mainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey("UIAppFonts") as NSArray` (or something similar, I don't speak Swift, not sure about the syntax). Then, you should be able to get the font names I guess. Inspired from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805410/getting-data-from-the-info-plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the info in the Info.plist, you can use [`objectForInfoDictionaryKey()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/objectForInfoDictionaryKey:) with [`UIAppFonts`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18) for the key.

I don't speak Swift, and I don't know if the code compile, but you should be able to get the idea.

```
let fonts = NSBundle.mainBundle.objectForInfoDictionaryKey(UIAppFonts) as NSArray
```

That should give you the array of the fonts. It's up to you then to construct the `UIFont` objects.

Comment: I voted up your question because you are only new on SO, but because even if you are new, you showed your attempts and not just asked for "free code".

Comment: Thank You :-)... I got stuck further, Now i am able to get .ttf file names, but not able to get the font family out of this.