# generate xcode warning if some keys are missing in info.plist?

Tags: xcode

is it possible to generate xcode warning if some keys (for example **URL types**) doesnot exist in info.plist,
or is there any way to remind such kind of issues
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9530129/1270586) with [this](http://shitmores.blogspot.ro/2011/04/xcode-tip-make-use-of-warning-directive.html)

You basically read the info.plist and check if key exists, if not, add warning (tho i'm not sure this will work because #warning directive might be called even if it doesn't enter the if statement). Test it and see what happens.