# Get programmatically NSExtensionAttributes dictionary in iOS 8 custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, custom-keyboard

I'm developing a custom keyboard for iOS 8, and I need to get keyboard language code, i.e "en-US","es-ES" etc. These codes are set in Info.plist file for each extension, in `NSExtensionAttributes` dictionary (see attached image). How to get programmatically `NSExtensionAttributes` dictionary?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530075/ios-access-app-info-plist-variables-in-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following solution:

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSDictionary *extentionDictionary = infoDict[@"NSExtension"];
NSDictionary *extentionAttributesDictionary = extentionDictionary[@"NSExtensionAttributes"];
NSString *languageCode = extentionAttributesDictionary[@"PrimaryLanguage"];
```

Comment: Is there a way to set these values programatically?