# How can you read values from Info.plist in build settings?

Tags: ios, plist

Currently, I have a custom user defined build settings in which I set the DISPLAY_NAME.

Then, in the General tab of Build Settings, in the display name column, I fetch this value as $(DISPLAY_NAME) from my user defined build settings.

I want to instead read the Display Name and set the general build settings from my Info.plist file. How can I do this?

Comment: This is the similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530075/ios-access-app-info-plist-variables-in-code

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood my question. I want to access Info.Plist in my build settings menu. Not in my code.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following code.

**Read info.plist file.**

```
NSDictionary *infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *value = [infoDict objectForKey:@"keyName"];
```

> infoDictionary: A dictionary, constructed from the bundle's Info.plist
>   file, that contains information about the receiver.

**Read a custom .plist file**

```
   NSString *file = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:"nameOfPlist" ofType:@"plist"];

    if (!file) {
        NSLog(@"Please add a plist config file to your project.");
        return nil;
    }

    NSDictionary *plistDict =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood my question. I want to access Info.Plist in my build settings menu. Not in my code